# can bootstrap modal open different pages

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

i have like 20 links on a page and all of them open the same modal but with different sets of content..

the links are like :

```
<a href="/applications/upcoming/2017-04-30/VISA/0"  data-target="#globalactions3" data-toggle="modal">978</a>

<a href="/applications/upcoming/2017-03-31/VISA/2"  data-target="#globalactions3" data-toggle="modal">6</a>
```

however problem is that the modal is filled with the content from the first click and then remains .. is it possible that the modal is updated with the content related to each click ...

as i dont want to have 20+ modals on the page ... must be simpler solution ???

Answer (score 2):

i don't know where you are redirecting your page i'm considering links are null i.e href="#"
you need to write a script for that and specify different id's to your links,
in your case it would be

```
<a href="/applications/upcoming/2017-04-30/VISA/0" id="modal1"  data-
        target="#globalactions3" data-toggle="modal">978</a>

 <a href="/applications/upcoming/2017-03-31/VISA/2" id="modal2"  data-
    target="#globalactions3" data-toggle="modal">6</a>
```

and paste this javascript

```
  <script>
 $('#globalactions3').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $(this).find('.modal-body').html('Fired By: ' + e.relatedTarget.id);
   })
</script>
```

here is the jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/bizamajig/THBm7/12/

Comment: thanks - however you are populating the modal with source ? i need to populate with the content from hrefs as per above  ie "/applications/upcoming/2017-03-31/VISA/2" how do i do that ?

Comment: it's impossible to tell you without looking into your code please do share your code